# Stemming from a list in python

Tags: python, list, stemming

How can I apply stemming to below list in python? Please help thank you.

NOT:I also need outcome to be list.

```
 documents =[['advertisement', 'playing', 'measurement'], ['time','cars','going']]
```

Comment: What is `stemming`.

Comment: I also need outcome to be list thank you